# How to change the primary color of NuxtUi programatically

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When unsing the [NuxtUi](https://ui.nuxt.com/) Framework, how can I change the primary color programmatically.

To change it manually, I can change the value in app.config.ts

```js
export default defineAppConfig({
  ui: {
    primary: 'green',
  //primary:'sky',
    gray: 'cool',
  },
});
```

Background: would like to create a color change button, something similar to what
is on the [NuxtUi](https://ui.nuxt.com/) Homepage in the right upper corner.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below code to handle the change in color:

```
const config = useAppConfig()
if (condition) {
   config.ui.primary = 'blue'
   config.ui.gray = 'slate'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const theme = useAppConfig()

<button @click="() => theme.ui.primary = 'sky'"></button>
```